# React js call the function and render the response in new page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to `React js` and `hooks` concept, I have search text box, where I input the employee id, it is calling new function  which calls the api, to get employee details. What i want to achieve is, the response value from the `GetEmployeeDetails(data)` method should bind details into new page. currently i am getting below error. Below is my code.

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Buffer } from "buffer";


function QueryEmployee() {

    const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState()
    const [api_response, setAPIResponse] = useState();
    const [employee_id, Set_employee_id] = useState({
        id: "",
      });

  //Handle the onSubmit
  function handleSubmitClick() {
    try {
      Set_employee_id({ id: textInput });
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e.message);
    }
    
  }

useEffect(() => {

  const fetchData = async (employee_id) => {
  try {
        const resp = await axios.post(
        config.SERVER_URL + "/api/getEmployee/",employee_id);
        setAPIResponse(resp.data);

       }catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
     };

    fetchData(employee_id)
     .catch(console.error);

  }, [employee_id]);


const RenderSearch = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          aria-describedby="button-addon2"
          id="txt_employee_id"
          name="id"
          placeholder="employee_id"
          onChange={(e) => setTextInput(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button
            class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
            type="button"
            id="button-addon2"
            onClick={() => handleSubmitClick()}
          >
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
 }

 const RenderEmployeeInfo = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Employee Info</h1>
      </div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {api_response === null ? <RenderEmployeeInfo /> : <RenderSearch />}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can't use hooks inside a sub function (GetEmployeeDetails). To do a async call you can make use of useEffect inside your main component. Doing inside any other helper sub-function will generate warnings and error for you

Comment: `GetEmployeeDetails` here seems to be a functional component on its own, which should render on the UI like `<GetEmployeeDetails data={someData} />`. If you want to create a function that is just supposed to return JSX, you have to exclude hooks from that function. Then you'd be able to call that type of function on the UI i.e. return statement like `GetEmployeeDetails(someData)`

Comment: Moreover, `onClick` handlers are `void` It doesn't make any sense to return a component on the click. What you *can* do is change a state on click, and place a conditional rendering on the  `QueryEmployee` component

Comment: i have updated the code,  but i am still not able to render into new page once i received the response.

Comment: useEffect is not able  `RenderEmployeeInfo` once i it receive  the response from API. Is it possible to navigate and bind the value in new page when `setAPIResponse` receive value ?